# How to create machine keys over IIS?

Tags: iis, machinekey, servermanager

I have created machine key over IIS for some purpose. However I am worried what happens if I push new build over server.

Will my machine keys be removed as I have created them on server directly?
Also, I have created machine key on the server name directly. I think if you do this machine keys will be applied to all the websites created under server. If not then what is right way.

My settings are as follows.

[Machine key settings on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fpxd.png)

Please help.

Comment: Unless you specify a machine key attribute in your site Web.Config, these machine keys that you have set using the GUI will not be overwritten. You can find the machine keys that you set in the GUI in you applicationHost.config file. It's normally at this location C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

Answer (score 0):

If you have created machine key for a website, it would be added under system.web section in your web.config. After pushing new built will remove your old machine key as your `web.config` file will also replace. You can backup your machine key and use later.

Machine key contains below sections:

- Encryption Method
- Decryption Method
- Validation Key
- Decryption Key

After replacing you built you can create machine key again using same protocols and keys (from backed-up machine key) with GUI or simply copy past under system.web section in your `web.config`.